# Why would a stat() call return am incorrect value of zero(0) for file size?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm running a windows c++ multithreaded app in which one instance/thread of the server class is appending to the file. Other threads run client instances which only load up the file upon
each client's startup.
When I get to within 2k bytes of the end of loading the file I check to see if the file has changed
in size, so I know to update how many total bytes to read. Once in a while the file size
I get back is erroneously determined to be zero(0). I am using the stat call below for this. When zero is returned, then as a sanity check, I then call getFileSizeWithTellg() to see what it returns and it returns the expected non-zero value. A value that is the same or greater than the initial value.
I realize that the cast to unsigned int could be problematic, but the files are never
larger than 5 mgBytes.

What could be causing the stat() call to return a zero value, when the ..Tellg call doesn't?
Thanks for any insight into this.

/

```
/ snippets from methods in different classes
//
// from client class
ifstream fileSeqIn
fileSeqIn.open(fName.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary |ios::ate); 
// to get initial size
size = fileSeqIn.tellg();
fileSeqIn.seekg(0, ios::beg);


// later to determine if the file has grown
struct stat filestatus;
unsigned int size;
if (stat(fName, &filestatus ) == 0) {
     size = (unsigned int)filestatus.st_size;   
}

//
unsigned int getFileSizeWithTellg(char *fname)
{
    // get length of file
    is.open (fname, ios::binary );
    is.seekg (0, ios::end); 
    length = is.tellg();
    is.close();
    return(length);
}


//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// from server class
ofstream fileSeqOut;
fileSeqOut.open(fName.c_str(), ios::app | ios::out |ios::ate |ios::binary);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One significant difference: `stat` returns the system's view of the size of the file; `tellg` returns a value dependend on the internal state of the stream.  File bases streams are buffered, and the data may not be passed on to the system until you flush or close the file.  Do you get the same difference if you precede the call to `stat` with a flush of the stream?

Comment: To be a bit more specific: The stat() call returns the file size as returned by FindFirstFileEx - this information is not reliable until the file is closed.

Comment: It's been fairly random. But I was not flushing after the writes. But now I am. Also, at the beginning of the load I use tellg. When I get to near the end I use stat because it doesn't change the file pointer location, whereas I would need to move to ed of file then call tellg and reposition back to where I was, which is just a little bit more code. But that may be the way to go. Dong this in conjuction with flushing after each write on the writing thread should work properly. Correct?

Comment: If you want accurate information about the state of the file and you have the file handle, call into APIs that use the handle, not APIs that use the file name.  In general, the APIs that use the file name will be less accurate than APIs which use a handle (the handle will always reflect the most recent filesystem measurement of the state of the file).

Comment: @LarryOsterman There should be no difference, provided the name refers to the same file.

Comment: @AlKurlansky If `tellg` works, then you don't need to flush; whether `tellg` gives you something useful or not depends on the implementation (but if you're using `stat`, you already depend on the implementation).  `stat` will, of course, only report the bytes you've actually output the system, so you need the flush.  A better system than either might be to install a filtering streambuf which counts the bytes sent to it.

Comment: @James: That's not been my experience.  In general, filesystems don't update the directory information (where FindFirstFile goes) until the file is closed or flushed (for performance reasons).  As a result, if you ask the filesystem for the size of the file (with tellg, for example), you'll get a dramatically more reliable answer.

Comment: @LarryOsterman I'll admit that my experience is largely Unix, where the information is held in something called an inode.  This is cached in system memory, and will only be written back to disk sometime in the future---possibly seconds after the file is closed.  But it is managed as a cache; any attempt to access it will be caught by the OS, and will use the in memory copy.  And it must be updated with each actual system call, since other programs can see it.  I would consider any other behavior a serious bug in the OS.

Comment: @James: Effectively the same thing is true in Windows.  On Windows the information in the directory entry isn't updated on every write - on all filesystems, updating the directory entry can take a significant amount of time (it can potentially involve a disk read or write) so it's only done when absolutely necessary.  The information in the file handle is kept accurate all the time, the information in the directory entry isn't.  IIRC the same thing is true on *nix (at least it used to be) - information kept in the dirent isn't updated until the file is closed.

Comment: @LarryOsterman On Unix, at least since I've been using it (since around 1985), the fact that data was cached in system memory was transparent (unless the system crashed before it actually got written out).  Otherwise, it's a serious system bug.  Today, problems can occur on network mounted filesystems, because not all updates are immediately visible locally.  But all accesses from the local machine see the latest information.  I'm pretty sure that this is true under Windows as well, as I have code written under Unix which depends on it, and it works under Windows.

Comment: @James: On Windows, there are two separate structures - one for the file and another for the directory containing the file.  The file size read by FindFirstFile is read from the directory entry.  Updating both of these entries on every write would introduce significant performance penalties, so the directory entry is only updated when the file data is flushed to disk.  An alternative implementation would be to have each FindFirstFile call go to the file entries, but that would significantly slow down directory enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

If what **Larry Osterman** said is true, using [GetFileInformationByHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might solve the problem.

Comment: You or anyone else can verify that Mr. Osterman is indeed speaking the truth by inspecting `crt-src\stat.c` somewhere in your MSVS installation directory.

Comment: One *minor* caveat to using GetFileInformationByHandle - I believe it requires that the file be opened for FILE_QUERY_INFORMATION access - if you opened the file for GENERIC_READ, this will work without a problem, but if you only opened the file for GENERIC_WRITE, it won't.